# Android: Adding new entry in Array ListView

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I am working on a project with 2 screens. The first screen involves a ListView containing all the top grossing movies of all time. Each row contains:

a.) Movie Title
b.) Earnings
c.) Year released

All are arranged by XML, and each movie is declared in a string-array in the strings.xml resource, accessed by a for loop inside the coding proper. Clicking the Menu button, gives you a choice to ADD another entry. Clicking this will redirect the user to another screen containing 3 Empty Edit Text fields. These correspond to the Movie title, Earnings and year Released respectively, and the user can input their movies in them.

Here is the strings .xml (snippet since too long):

```
 <string-array name="title_array">
        <item>Avatar</item>
        <item>Titanic</item>
        <item>The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King</item>
        <item>Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Mans Chest</item>
        <item>Toy Story 3</item>
        <item>Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides</item>
    </string-array>
```

Assume I also have the corresponding gross-array and year-array.

Here is the for loop proper (Via Custom Adapter):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] titleList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title_array);
        String[] grossList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gross_array);
        String[] dateList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date_array);

        ArrayList<Lab6_082588FetchDetails> results = new   ArrayList<Lab6_082588FetchDetails>();

    for (int i = 0; i < titleList.length; i++) {
        Lab6_082588FetchDetails sr = new Lab6_082588FetchDetails();
        sr.setTitle(titleList[i]);
        sr.setGross(grossList[i]);
        sr.setDate(dateList[i]);
        results.add(sr);
    }
```

My problem is that, sure, I can add another entry and use set notifyDataSetChanged(); but this wouldn't "Permanently" save the new entries if the user exits and re-opens the application. My hypothesis is that one can probably alter the.xml string resource file by code, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you stored your Movie info in an SQLite database.

You could then use a `CursorAdapter`with you `ListView`.

Comment: Im afraid we are only limited to using ListView for now though

Comment: you use ListView for th UI and SQLite to store the data

Comment: I mean, we can;t use SQLite since wer enot in that lesson yet. In short, were limited.

Comment: But is there anyway to do this using just a Custom Adapter and String array?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change resource files. You will have to use other methods of persisting data.

Either use SQLite or file for this.

Since you have not yet reached your SQLite lesson, you can try files, if not files then you can try shared preferences.

Comment: Hm. Since you say it's not possible to change resource file, is there any other way to make the added entries "permanent" without resorting to shared prefs or SQLite? I mean of course, not touching the .xml file at all since it cant be editted through code.

Comment: Sorry pal, you will have to use either file, sqlite or shared preferences to persist any data.